# Check Conditions on Geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a `GeoDataFrame` : `df`

```
   gid  complement  geom
0   0   None    POINT (601719.697 6316169.550)
1   1   None    POINT (889885.470 6766441.264)
2   2   None    POINT (841297.833 6819921.974)
3   3   None    POINT (868509.310 6741434.511)
4   4   None    POINT (868800.981 6741780.168)
...     ...     ...     ...
2230    735794  None    POINT (928202.527 6895078.782)
2231    735795  None    POINT (958274.959 6891683.317)
```

I tried to convert the `geometry` to `WKT` but some `None` geometries failed it.
I tried to look at the rows with missing geometries with :

```
df.loc[df.loc[:, 'geom'].isna(), :]
>>>IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I found it the `gid` corresponding to the empty geometries and tried :

```
df.loc[df.loc[:, 'gid'].isin([90138, 424617, 559838, 565628]), :]
>>>IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I really do not understand why this behaviour is raised. Is it proper to GeoPandas ? How should I solve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're over-complicating your query. Try:

```py
df[ df.geom.isna() ]
```